# Customise .NET WiX installer image

Tags: c#, .net, wix, installation

I have written a custom GUI for my WiX installer which works great, the only problem is the initial .NET installer looks pretty shoddy.  We use WPF for the customised GUI which obviously cannot be used to update the .NET installer but I'd like to update the red CD image.  How can I do this?

I found [this article](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/WixUI_dialog_library.htm) explaining how to change some images but they dont match the size of the cd image

[image]

**Update**

As per Bob's comment I tried adding the following in `BootstrapperApplicationRef` to no avail

```
<bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        LicenseFile="path\to\license.rtf"
        LogoFile="../emlogo.png"
        />
```

Comment: why did you block "Estate Manager"?  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it with the [WixManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bal_xsd_wixmanagedbootstrapperapplicationhost.htm)/@LogoFile attribute.

Comment: I tried that and nothing happened... does it have to be a specific type?

Comment: If you're using your own managed BA, you must use WixManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost, not WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the WIX source code it looks like that image might be from bannrbmp.bmp under src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\Bitmaps.  (If it is it must have been flipped)  but  you can just browse to that file and change it, or else in the installer change the file location that is pointed to bannrbmp.bmp to be pointed to the file you want to use.

Or is that installer from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes this is the correct image, how do I get my custom one into my application? Ive tried using http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/WixUI_dialog_library.htm but i've obviously set it up wrong

Comment: I tried this, it didnt work.  I think this only affects the stock installation dialogs rather than the .NET one